# Hide Column with Php

Tags: php

I have a question regarding hide empty column.

How to hide **< th>SURNAME< /th>** head column when I have empty column?

In next days i'm working to swith to mysqli all queries :-)

```
QUERY
$query = " SELECT * FROM users ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result); 

TABLE
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">

 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>NAME</th>
         <th>SURNAME</th>
     </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num) {
            $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
            $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
            $surname = mysql_result($result,$i,"surname");
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $surname; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Just do a check before echoing the `<th>`(and the corresponding `<td>`) and see if there are results for the surname. I'm assuming you might not know using only the `$num`-variable? (Ie you can have a first name but not a surname?). If it's either/or, you can just do a check with the `$num`-variable. Also, there is no need to assign the `mysql_result()` calls to variables, you can just echo them out directly within the `<td>` (adding them to variables creates unnecessary load).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To HIDE column, you need to check before while.

```
   $array_surname = array();
    while($res_head_surname = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array_surname[] = $res_head_surname;
    }
```

After this, insert condition as you like and add to header table:

```
<?php if ($show_surname == 1) {?><th>SURNAME</th><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this ! Just put a if to check if surname if present or not. And also include the  tag in the echo.

```
QUERY
$query = " SELECT * FROM users ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($result); 
TABLE
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">

 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>NAME</th>
         <th>SURNAME</th>
     </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num) {
            $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
            $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
            $surname = mysql_result($result,$i,"surname");
    ?>

    <tr>
```

> ```
>        <?php echo "<td>".$name."</td>"; ?>
>         <td><?php if($surname){echo "<th>".$surname."</th>";} ?></td>
> ```

```
    </tr>

    <?php
        $i++;
        }
    ?>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Its <th>SURNAME</th> !!